# Why it changes when I move my view around the model with the shader which should not react to the view?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

It is a sample in 《Unity Shaders and Effects Cookbook》.

It should not react to view change but it does.

There are some pictures of a capsule in different directions.
    [image: 01]
    [image: 02]
    [image: 03]

Is there anyone can hely me?

I use unity 5.0

```
Shader"CookbookShaders/Chapter05/LitSphere"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTint ("Diffuse Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NormalMap ("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Unlit vertex:vert
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _NormalMap;
        float4 _MainTint;

        inline fixed4 LightingUnlit (SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed atten)
        {
            fixed4 c = fixed4(1,1,1,1);
            c.rgb = c * s.Albedo;
            c.a = s.Alpha;
            return c;
        }

        struct Input 
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float2 uv_NormalMap;
            float3 tan1;
            float3 tan2;
        };

        void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o) 
        {
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);

            TANGENT_SPACE_ROTATION;
            o.tan1 = mul(rotation, UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV[0].xyz);     
            o.tan2 = mul(rotation, UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV[1].xyz);
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
        {
            float3 normals = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_NormalMap,  IN.uv_NormalMap));
            o.Normal = normals;

            float2 litSphereUV;
            litSphereUV.x = dot(IN.tan1, o.Normal);
            litSphereUV.y = dot(IN.tan2, o.Normal);

            half4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, litSphereUV*0.5+0.5);

            o.Albedo = c.rgb * _MainTint;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    //FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: @Ale_32 No.I only create a default capsule provided by Unity and add the shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is no viewDir, UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV changes as view changes.